# Can I put a junction box in the ceiling accessible by removing a bath fan

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Can I put a junction box in the ceiling which is only accessible by removing the bathroom fan. My existing fan has conduit from the switch coming in on the top and then conduit on the side going to the shower light. I have not been able to find a replacement fan that has two knock outs so I can connect both pieces of conduit. My thought is to connect the two with a junction box and then connect the fan to the junction box with FMC. The junction box would be accessible by removing the fan which would be held in place with two screws. I have a feeling this is not allowed, if  so what other options do I have.
[image: Top of fan]
[image: Fan Wiring]

Comment: I take it the wiring on the new fans also comes into the rear portion of the fan?

Comment: All the fans I've found the wiring comes in on the side and it's on the wrong side. In the top picture of the existing fan you can barely see the conduit and the exhaust on the far side. All the replacement fans have the knock out on the near side.

Comment: So they have the knockout/wiring compartment on the side opposite the exhaust duct eh?

Comment: Yes, I could flip the fan 180 degrees so the knockout is on the right side but then I need to do a 180 with the duct. If I do that then I'm not sure I could mount it to the joist it's currently mounted to. Ultimately I may have to start opening boxes at the store to see which one I could make work.

Answer (score 1):

You can drill a hole if there aren't enough knock-outs, but you still need to have enough room in there to make all joins you need.

Comment: This looks like the best answer so far. I can eliminate some wires, currently the shower light and fan are on separate switches. I'm going to put them on one switch so that's two wires in there I can eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar but attached a box extender to the fan unit. A box extender is like a junction box without a bottom. By having it attached to the fan the inspector allowed it. I know he would not have allowed it attached to the structure.

Comment: This is a good solution especially if there is not enough room in the fans junction box for all the connections needed.